# How does real server, direct return server (DRS), reply to client if a load balancer (LB) uses port address translation (PAT)?

Tags: ip, load-balancing, tcp, port-forwarding, socket

Direct Return Server overview:

The DRS allows real servers to directly reply to a client without going through load balancer (LB). The LB ip (VIP) is configured as a loopback (localhost) ip for the real servers. Both the LB and real server are installed on layer 2 OSI model. When a client send a request to VIP, the LB forward traffic to one of the real server. The LB only changes the destination MAC and forward to a real server. The real server sends a response directly to client because the loop back IP is public and same as VIP.

Questions:

Let a real server running webserver on port 4001 and client makes a request to VIP and port 80. The LB forward the traffic to real server port (4001). LB doesn't change anything in the packet except for MAC address.

Q1: What will be source port # (80,4001) when server reply to client?

Q2: Will the subsequent client requests, assuming TCP connection still alive, bypass LB? Please explain why and why not.

Q3: How will a TCP handshake look like if DRS LB used and webserver running on port 4001?

Answer (score 1):

With Direct Return, there's no translation by the load balancer. You need to take care that the requests are routed to the LB which will then route them balanced to the clustered servers, based on their MAC address (derived from their interface IP address).

From the network perspective, the LB is just a gateway to the server and it treats the currently selected server (by load) as the gateway to its loopback/VIP address.

> Let a real server running webserver on port 4001 and client makes a
> request to VIP and port 80. The LB forward the traffic to real server
> port (4001). LB doesn't change anything in the packet except for MAC
> address.

That is correct.

> Q1: What will be source port # (80,4001) when server reply to client?

The server will reply from its port 80 (on the VIP/loopback interface). Anything else wouldn't work with the client.

> Q2: Will the subsequent client requests, assuming TCP connection still
> alive, bypass LB? Please explain why and why not.

Subsequent packets from the client are routed like the initial packet - through the load balancer. The load balancer is en route between clients and servers, so that direction always passes the LB.

> Q3: How will a TCP handshake look like if DRS LB used and webserver
> running on port 4001?

The TCP handshake is between the client (initiator) and the server (listener), completely normal. It's just the routing that's asymmetric: client→server goes through the LB, server→client bypasses the LB.

Even without any translation, the load balancer has to keep track of each session, so that the selected server doesn't change.

Comment: thank you for answering my questions. 
One final question... 

Loopback IP doesn't respond to ARP call. If the real servers were in different region (or subnet), how does LB forward to a real server in different region? 

(Note: It using IPv4 protocol and DRS)

Comment: The loopback interface is a virtual interface, it's not connected to a physical network, so there's no ARP. As I was trying to explain, you talk to it as you would to a remote IP address, through the IP address on the physical network as the gateway. That gateway (and the physical server) changes as determined by the load balancing algorithm.